# Is this concept of a button containing a textbox possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Recently I had been looking for a way to make the tabs in a `TabControl` editable and came across [This example](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radtabcontrol-how-to-make-the-tab-headers-editable-wpf.html) on telerik's website. That did exactly what I wanted but it got me thinking about a similar usage for buttons. I was wondering if it would be possible to use something like that and make a button that would show a textbox instead of the content presenter when say, you right click the button? I tried to make something like this work but so far have only ended up with a blank button.

```
<Button x:Name="SB" Height="222" Width="222" Click="SB_Click">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:SuperButton Content="{Binding Path=x, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Where x is a string variable and using the code behind from the link above (with a class name change, of course).

edit: This button will be in an itemscontrol, so I don't think naming the inner elements in xaml will work, but I do like the ease of Wolfgang's answer.

Comment: Sure its possible, though it looks like you are doing this the hard way :) Why not just set the Button's content property to a text box?

Answer (score 2):

[**The WPF Content Model**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is really flexible and allows literally *anything* inside *anything*.

This is perfectly valid XAML:

```
<Button>
    <TextBox/>
</Button>
```

Or even:

```
<Button>
    <MediaElement Source="C:\Videos\WildLife.wmv"/>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply host a (e.g.) label (TextBlock) with the text AND a `TextBox` inside the Button and set their `Visiblity` properties.
That way, if you right click the button, the `TextBox` shows up.

```
<Button>
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Text=normal button caption" x:Name="label" />
    <TextBox 
       x:Name="textbox"
      Text="visible on right click" 
      MouseRightButtonDown="HandleRightClick"/>
  </Grid>
</Button>
```

And then in your C# code create an event handler to set the Visiblity correctly.

```
void HandleRightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  label.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
  textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: How would I access the textboxes if the button will be inside an itemscontrol and naming won't be an option?